# SMPlayer not playing MP4 format

Tags: codecs, video-player, mplayer, mp4, smplayer

I am trying to run some MP4 videos on SMplayer , but the player is only playing the audio, and no video is visible. The same file I open in VLC player is showing video + audio. I like SMPlayer, as its better in usability, therefore looking for the solution of playing MP4 files in it.

Thanks

Comment: have you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras and w32codecs?

Comment: @Daniyal: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

For Playing Restricted Formats install ubuntu-restricted-extras

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: isn't that only for gstremer based apps¿

Comment: nope - all apps that want to play these media files (except VLC, which come with it's own)

Answer (score 3):

smplayer probably not working because video ID is set to 0.

don't know about other SW, but for me it worked, when I put into ~/.config/smplayer/smplayer.ini

under section [%GEneral]
put: (without quotes)
"current_video_id=1"

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! For what it's worth, this also solved the problem for me with SMPlayer on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in the present year of 2022. I verified that the codec streamers could display video with the following commands, and they all worked:
FFMPEG:
$ ffplay 'video name.mp4'
with gstreamer:
$ gst-play-1.0 'video name.mp4'
mplayer:
$ mplayer 'video name.mp4'

This was courtesy of the following post: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422025&p=13870148#post13870148

I ensured that the mpv 'Multimedia Engine' (located at Preferences → General tab) was indeed located at SMPlayer's designated/preferred location of: /snap/smplayer/64/usr/bin/mpv

I also used the 'other' location of a standalone mpv I installed separately, by manually specifying the path: /usr/bin/mpv

SMPlayer still refused to display the video, but could stream the audio.

Also there was no suitable 'Config' file (out of 49 with config string in their filename) to adjust according to mate-search-tool in the file path: /snap/smplayer/

In the Preference → Video, setting of SMPlayer, I changed the 'output driver' from 'default' to 'x11'. Video worked. Video files were encoded with MP4 and MKV(HEVC)

Also if you install SMPlayer with Snap repository, you'll need to go to 'Ubuntu Software' manager and adjust its permission to be able to read file off a removable drive like USB and encrypted partitions.

[image: SMPlayer setting location]